# WPF Rectangle.Fill method responsiveness

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

Quick performance question for c# / WPF.

I have a rectangle in a grid:

```
<Rectangle Name="NewPage" Grid.Row="1" Width="42" Height="59.4" Stroke="Black" MouseEnter="Rectangle_MouseEnter_1" MouseLeave="NewPage_MouseLeave_1" />
```

that I perform a fill on MouseEnter and MouseLeave using:

```
private void Rectangle_MouseEnter_1(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
   SolidColorBrush blueBrush = new SolidColorBrush();
   blueBrush.Color = Colors.Blue;
   NewPage.Fill = blueBrush;
}

private void NewPage_MouseLeave_1(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
   SolidColorBrush whiteBrush = new SolidColorBrush();
   whiteBrush.Color = Colors.White;
   NewPage.Fill = whiteBrush;
}
```

The desired goal is to highlight the rectangle as the mouse is moved over it and will allow a click later on to do some more workk.

The issue I'm having is the responsiveness of the fill method. I can move the mouse clear across the rectangle before it is filled. It also doesn't start filling for about 15 seconds after starting the application.

Any tips/guidance on this would be most appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: just copied it to a new project and it seems fine to me.

Comment: Ok. Does that mean the issue could be local hardware related? Would this task take all that much processing power? Or are their project settings that need to be tailored somewhere for performance?

Comment: Any chance you're connected via remote desktop or VNC?  Or running something compute intensive on the UI thread?

Comment: VPN to work. Really? I'll check it out when I get in. If this is the case then egg on my face and kudos to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem will be caused because the `Rectangle` is `Null` when the application starts, this means you wont get a `MouseOver` event because it goes straight though, It will only turn blue when the `Stroke` picks up the `MouseOver`, try setting the Rectangle to `White` in the xaml first.

```
<Rectangle Fill="White" Name="NewPage" Grid.Row="1" Width="42" Height="59.4" Stroke="Black" MouseEnter="Rectangle_MouseEnter_1" MouseLeave="NewPage_MouseLeave_1" />
```

But a better option would be to use a `Trigger` for this in the Xaml instead. This way you wont need any event handlers in your code behind, and you seperate your UI logic from your actual code base.

```
    <Rectangle Name="NewPage" Grid.Row="1" Width="42" Height="59.4" Stroke="Black" >
        <Rectangle.Style>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type Rectangle}">
                <Setter Property="Fill" Value="White" />
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True" >
                        <Setter Property="Fill" Value="Blue" />
                    </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </Rectangle.Style>
    </Rectangle>
```

Comment: Fantastic. That worked brilliantly. Simple and elegant, I like it. Thanks!